# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when loading external FAT-JARs in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, fatjar

- While trying to run a piece of code that used some `FAT JARs` (that share some common `submodules`) built using `sbt assembly`, I'm running into this nasty `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`
- The `JAR` is built on `EMR` itself (and not uploaded from some other environment), so *version conflict* in libraries / `Spark` / `Scala` etc is unlikely

---

My `EMR` environment:

- Release label: **emr-5.11.0**
- Hadoop distribution: **Amazon 2.7.3**
- Applications: **Spark 2.2.1, Zeppelin 0.7.3, Ganglia 3.7.2, Hive 2.3.2, Livy 0.4.0, Sqoop 1.4.6, Presto 0.187**

---

Project configurations:

- **Scala 2.11.11**
- **Spark 2.2.1**
- **SBT 1.0.3**

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the real culprit were the shared `submodules` in those `jars`.

Two `fat jars` built out of projects containing common `submodules` were leading to this conflict. Removing one of those `jars` resolved the issue.

---

I'm not sure if this conflict happened only under some particular circumstances or would always occur upon uploading such `jars` (that have same `submodules`) in `Zeppelin interpreter`, so still waiting for proper explanation.